# How can I keep my WPF UI available while running an operation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application that reads Excel sheets and shows the details in a Data Grid.

Main View Model has an abstract validation method that fills ValidateVM's with Data, puts them into an ObservableCollection and displays it on the Data Grid.

How can I keep the UI active/useable while it is performing the operation? I understand that I have to do this with the WPF Dispatcher by using threads but I don't know how and where.

Is it the validation method that needs to run on a new thread so it doesn't interfere with the View?

Comment: You have to do some form of Multitasking. If you use raw Threads, the BackgroundWorker, async..await, the Dispatcher or any of the other approaches is between unimportant and a minor detail.

Comment: "*I have to do this with the WPF Dispatcher by using threads*" - not at all. Use async/await. Threads and BackgroundWorker are no longer necessary nor recommendable.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post an example of your code. Here is a link to the guidelines for asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is getting loaded in response to a button click, check the return type of your event handler from `void` to `Task` and mark the method with the `async` keyword.

Something like this:

```
public async Task OnGetDataClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Data = await service.GetData();
}
```

You will need to change the return type of the method retreiving the data as well. Say your returning `ObservableCollection<T>`, change to `Task<ObservableCollection<T>>` and also add the `async` keyword. In your event handler, you need to await the result of the service call, as shown above.

If you're reading the data using an api that has asynch methods for reading, then your service could have a method like this:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<object>> GetDataAsync()
{
    return await api.GetDataAsync();
}
```

Otherwise, if you have to read the file synchronously, you could do it on another thread like this:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<object>> GetDataAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => api.getData());
}
```

Here's a link to Microsoft's documentation on async/await: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Also, dotnetpearls have some good examples: https://www.dotnetperls.com/async